# Invalid prop `data[0].value` of type `object` supplied to `ReactMinimalPieChart`, expected `number`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pie-chart

I am building a React dashboard web app with data being fetched from
 api. On passing data to the component it's giving the above error.

> Invalid prop `data[0].value` of type `object` supplied to `ReactMinimalPieChart`, expected `number`

```
"…0 A 25 25 0 1 1 NaN NaN"
```

```jsx
import PieChart from 'react-minimal-pie-chart';

render() {
    const { totalBudget, expenses } = this.state.jsonData;
    const total_Budget = this.state.jsonData.totalBudget;

    function noOfPage() {
      return Math.ceil(expenses.length / pageSize);
    }

    return (

        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6">
            <PieChart
              data={[
                { title: 'Total Budget', value: {totalBudget}, color: '#ccc' },
                { title: 'Total Expenses', value: 1200000, color: '#C13C37' }
              ]}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more info in order to someone be able to help you? Regards.

Comment: Try changing `value: {totalBudget}` to `value: totalBudget`